# Ruby: ActiveRecord relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I have some problems setting up my desired relationship in my application. Some help and hints would be appreciated!

**I have the following models:**

- User **(id, username)**
- Company **(id, name)**
- Campaign **(id, name, company_id)**
- Relationship **(user_id, company_id)**

The relationship is supposed to connect the user to many companies.
Company has_many campaigns.

I want to to connect all the campaigns related to the companies that the specific user follows.

Users > (Relationships) > Companies > Campaigns

I'd better not post some code since it's just a mess and not at all doing what I want.

I've also really tried to follow railstutorial.org, http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top and change it the way I want with no success.

I need your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be pretty straightforward! This is obviously pseudocode, but here you go:

```
User
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :companies, :through => :relationships
    has_many :campaigns, :through => :companies

Relationship
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :company

Company
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :users, :through => :relationships
    has_many :campaigns

Campaign
    belongs_to :company
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! My code wasn't so bad, most like yours but you had some relation that made it work.

It is set up now and I can for instance do `User.first.companies` and get all of the companies that the first user are following. But what I wanted was to be able to iterate through **campaigns** (that belongs to the companies I follow). And I don't see how I should do that relation, it's kind of a through => through?

Comment: You can't use has_many through unless the join table has a primary key (id).

Comment: `has_many :campaigns, :through => :companies` in the User model seems to make it work?